# Elegant way to handle goroutine in IO wait state in GRPC

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

Our server (grpc-gateway + grpc) is running on K8S with go 1.13, and terminate stack information

```
    Last State:    Terminated
      Reason:      Error
      Message:     o.(*Reader).fill(0xc002ec78c0)
                   /Users/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:100 +0x103
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc002ec78c0, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc002e79ad0)
  /Users/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:138 +0x4f
net/http.(*conn).readRequest(0xc00245a000, 0x1ef4800, 0xc000be7780, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:962 +0xb3b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00245a000, 0x1ef4800, 0xc000be7780)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1817 +0x6d4
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2928 +0x384

goroutine 8724981 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f5d3a8f84e8, 0x72, 0xffffffffffffffff)
  /Users/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:184 +0x55
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc000155d98, 0x72, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xffffffffffffffff)
  /Users/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87 +0x45
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
  /Users/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:92
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc000155d80, 0xc00138b000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
  /Users/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:169 +0x1cf
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc000155d80, 0xc00138b000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc00142b9e8, 0x4ce13d, 0xc000155d80)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:202 +0x4f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc0000dd690, 0xc00138b000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/net.go:184 +0x68
net/http.(*connReader).Read(0xc001e9b050, 0xc00138b000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:785 +0xf4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc0021fe060)
  /Users/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:100 +0x103
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc0021fe060, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00142bad0)
  /Users/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:138 +0x4f
net/http.(*conn).readRequest(0xc0008f43c0, 0x1ef4800, 0xc000503640, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:962 +0xb3b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0008f43c0, 0x1ef4800, 0xc000503640)
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1817 +0x6d4
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
  /Users/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2928 +0x384

      Exit Code:    2
```

Per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238695/goroutine-in-io-wait-state-for-long-time), one possible solution is

```
>  s := new(http.Server)
>  // ...
>  s.ReadTimeout = 5 * time.Second
>  s.WriteTimeout = 5 * time.Second
>  // ...
```

However, we failed to find the `ReadTimeout` from `grpc.NewServer`, is there anything are we missing? or how to handle goroutine in IO wait state in GRPC more elegantly?

grpc version is `v1.21.1`

Answer (score 1):

gprc.[NewServer](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#NewServer) allows for zero or more `ServerOption` during creation:

```
func NewServer(opt ...ServerOption) *Server
```

while there does not appear to be a `ReadTimeout` or `WriteTimeout` equivalent to `http.Server` you could try `keepalive.ServerParameters`:

```
type ServerParameters struct {
    MaxConnectionIdle     time.Duration // The current default value is infinity.
    MaxConnectionAge      time.Duration // The current default value is infinity.
    MaxConnectionAgeGrace time.Duration // The current default value is infinity.
    Time                  time.Duration // The current default value is 2 hours.
    Timeout               time.Duration // The current default value is 20 seconds.
}
```

(full docs [keepalive.ServerParameters](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/keepalive#ServerParameters))

and tune say `keepalive.ServerParameters.Time` to something lower than 2 hours:

```
srv := grpc.NewServer(
    keepalive.ServerParameters{Time:5*time.Minute},
)
```

This will lower connection reuse - but will also free up client connections that are long since dead.

Answer (score -1):

You use Context with Timeout.

https://golang.org/pkg/context/

Comment: That's a client-side solution. The OP is asking about the server-side.

Comment: What? context.Context is server-side! http.request.context()

Comment: https://ieftimov.com/post/make-resilient-golang-net-http-servers-using-timeouts-deadlines-context-cancellation/

Comment: That is the server-side request context once a request is being handled. It can be used to detect cancelation of a live request. What if the client has a connection, but hasn't sent a request yet?